# PDO fetch table not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm try to use the following script to fetch user data from a table

```
//if session detected connect to database using pdo
$db = getConnection();

$user = getUser();

//qry the databse
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID = :email");
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $user);


echo "<br></br>
    <table border='2' align='left' width='700'>
    <th align='left'>HolidayID</th>
    <th align='left'>SubscriberID</th>
    <th align='left'>Link</th>
    <th align='left'>Published</th>
    <th align='left'>Title</th>
    <th align='left'>Description</th>
    <th align='left'>Saved</th>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>";

while($obj = $stmt->fetchObject())

{
    echo "<tr><td>".$obj->holidayID."</td><td>".$obj->subcriberID."</td><td>".$obj->link."</td><td>".
    $obj->pubDate."</td><td>".$obj->title ."<td>".$obj->dateSaved."</td><br/>\n"."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>";
```

I don't receive any error messages, but neither do I recieved the desire output. All I get is the table headings, what am doing wrong?

Comment: Good for you for choosing PDO! You're a rare one around these lands. How are you checking for errors? Have you set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: Also, `<br>` is an invalid (and unnecessary really) inside of a table, you should be getting rid of it.

Comment: yeah i have the error checks with the connection in the functions file, i was recieving an error concerning the :user but after i switched to using this function to find value 'function getUser(){
 $user = false;

 if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
   $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  
  return $user;
  } '  but i just recieved an empty table

Comment: Silly me, missed the obvious. See my answer.

Comment: @user1302775 - Code in comments is unreadable but you can edit the original question and add further details there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't execute your query.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

After a query is prepared, and all parameters/values are bound, you need to execute your query.

Comment: tried placing the execute directly under the bind param but still nothing?

Comment: @user1302775 - Please copy and paste your code into the question. Actual code is always better than a vague description of it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Yes, though he should still leave the original code so that his question will make sense (otherwise it will have valid code which works fine).

Comment: thanks for the help found the problem, it was an error in the login script defining the username, qry was working and displayed no results because there were no matches